# Is there a way to reload/refresh entire dom - based location, without reloading the browser window?

Tags: javascript, ajax, animation, dom, webflow

is this possible? I am using this for smooth async pagetransitions, but the problem is that presenting new elements to DOM breaks all javascript animations generated in the system (webflow), and it´s not possible to grab just the animations code from webflow, to reinitiate the animations after the pagetransition ajax load.

Actually - I want the effect of location.reload(); without the glitch of actually reloading the window. Is that possible?

Or is there another way of refreshing the DOM so that all new elements are recognized, and make sure the animations will work?

I have tried refreshing the entire system generated script (25.000 lines of js. code), and that makes somethings work, but not everything. Eg. scroll into view animations don´t work.

/Hans

Comment: Are you after something like the upcoming view-transition API? https://github.com/WICG/view-transitions/blob/main/explainer.md

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can try duplicating the tab, then refresh the duplicate.